# git checkout filename reverted my last commit

Tags: git

I have just a master branch in my git repo. I commited a change to my file yesterday night:

```
git add filename
git commit -m 'my message'
```

This morning I was making some more changes that later I wanted to revert (I had not added these changes to the index, they were only in my filesystem). I had a look [here](http://book.git-scm.com/4_undoing_in_git_-_reset,_checkout_and_revert.html) and used the following command:

```
git checkout path/to/file/filename
```

Now I noticed that my las commit was gone. I did a search and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348292/lost-last-git-commit), but it refers to git revert.

If I do git log, my last commit shows up there, but the changes in the file are not. And if I do git status I get no changes showing and "nothing added to commit" message.

Why did it revert my last commit? How do I re-apply the commit?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this. EDIT: Okay, I realise that doesn't mean much. Maybe you could create a test repository and test for this behaviour? and `reflog` should give you your work best. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks. I did git reflog and it shows all my commits.

Comment: If this should not be happening, I will doubleckeck whether the changes were really reverted.

Comment: Yep, know I see in the git log -p that I did add several files, but not the one I did checkout today... I didnt see it listed as Modified in the git status, thogh... any way I think I can reapply changes manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If for whatever reason your commit from yesterday has disappeared, the first place to look for said commit is in the **[reflog](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html)**.
See for instance "[how to undo a checkout in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601911/how-to-undo-a-checkout-in-git)"

```
git reflog
git reset --hard <sha from reflog><
```

You can even "[Query `git reflog` for all commits to a specific file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311226/query-git-reflog-for-all-commits-to-a-specific-file)".

Comment: Thanks, I have a lot to learn with git, just started this week. Will checkout your links.

Looking at the log -p I saw that some files were well add to the commit, while others were not. I did add them by the extension git add *.png and add *.css (may be I was in the wrong pwd)