# How to revert wrong fetch from remote operation in git

Tags: git, git-fetch

I have some git repo with alot of remotes, some of remote branches a unique and i have not local tracking branches for it.

Today I did mistake on changing a remote url (I used remote1 instead of remote2).

After `git fetch --all` my remote1 was rewritten (i see + before commit sha)

It's very bad, because remote1 now not accessible for me, and i cant modify url back and fetch.

Is it possible restore remote1 branches from my local repo after this wrong fetch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git logs everything that happened to references (like branch tips and remote branch tips) in the reflog, you have to dive in it to find the previous SHA of the remote.

To search the git reflog, enter `git reflog`, and search for the before-last mention of (refs/remotes/remote/branch). It will give you a SHA.

Then you can restore the remote reference to this SHA by running

```
git update-ref refs/remotes/remote1/branch
```

EDIT you can try to find dangling commits with [Lost Last Git Commit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2348292/11343).

Comment: I understood the idea, but cant find anything about remote1/branch in reflog. Alot of trash like "checkout: moving" and "merge: Fast-forward" but nothing interesting.

Comment: @KorjavinIvan: sorry no clue... you can try to find dangling commits with http://stackoverflow.com/q/2348292/11343

Comment: Yep git fsck was the answer. Thank you!