# GIT Help - Committed to HEAD then switched branch and all commits are GONE

Tags: git, github

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lost Last Git Commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348292/lost-last-git-commit)
>   [gitx How do I get my ‘Detached HEAD’ commits back into master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845505/gitx-how-do-i-get-my-detached-head-commits-back-into-master)

I am using GitHub for Mac. I finished committing all of my changes, then realized that I was committing to the `HEAD`. So I clicked on my `master` branch, and now all of my commits (and thousands of lines of code) have disappeared. Please help me!

Thanks.

Comment: `HEAD` is an alias for the tip of your currently checked out branch. So what branch were you on? I.e. what branch do you mean when you say `HEAD`? Your changes should still be on that branch.

Comment: I used http://sitaramc.github.com/concepts/detached-head.html to find the command `git reflog show HEAD@{now} -10`. Sorry for the thoughtless post, I think we all know how scary it is to lose so much work... now I'm just trying to merge to my new branch. I've copied the commits to a new branch, `master2`, but really want them on `master`

Comment: I see it is a duplicate. My bad. Weird that it didn't come up in my related questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is always "git reflog" to find old commits.

If you have not committed anything since then

git branch old-commits HEAD@{1}

should create "old-commits" branch that contains your old commits.

Then you can merge or rebase those commits on your master.